# Lexical issue in xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries, xcode6.3

I am working on a static library and a sample app, I started this static lib and sample app with `Xcode 6.1.1` and so it was working absolutely fine with this version of Xcode.

Now when I updated my Xcode to 6.3 last week my Sample app started giving me `lexical or preprocessor issue` and it is not recognising entry class file for **static library**. I didn't change any thing, it still working fine with the `Xcode 6.1.1`

**Update**
Here are the screenshot of Build settings for `Static Library` and `Test APP`

**Static Library-->**

[image: Static Library]

**Static Library build Phases -->**

[image]
**Test App-->**

[image: Test App]

**Build Phases for Test App.**
[image]

**I'm getting some new compile time error as below...**
[image]

above mentioned classes in images are classes from the static library(say, B) which has been included in the another library (say, A). this package included in a test app.

**and this is how my Header and user search path respectively looks...** 
[image: Header search path]

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide full error listing?

Comment: @ninjaproger sorry, I knew it's bit too late in replying you, but as they says better late than never. so the error  say 'lexical or preprocessor issue' and 'xyz.h' file not found and this xyz.h is just a entry point to my static library.

Comment: Could you please share any code? Without adding some info it's impossible to help you.

Comment: @Sulthan what exactly do you need to know, because I can't see any specific code that can be share? I have two static library and one static library using another library and this combination of library I'm using inside a test app.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your build phases for both your app itself (with the 'Link Binary with Libraries' section expanded) and the static library which contains the file that it says is not found (with the 'Compile Sources' section expanded)? Also, is the file that is not found within the main static library or within the library that the static library you are linking to is using?

Comment: did you delete the sample app and perform a "clean" and rebuild everything?

Comment: yes @MDB983, I did this so many time but no luck.

Comment: @SuryakantSharma Have you seen my comment above? May allow us to further help you with additional information

Comment: @Joshua: Apologies for replying late I was away from my computer. I have update my question. please have a look  if this can give you some clues.

Comment: @SuryakantSharma No worries. Thanks for the screenshots, could you also provide similar for the build **phases** section too?

Comment: @SuryakantSharma Thank you, what was the name of the file you tried to import that caused the error?

Comment: @Joshua I have done something I don't know what though, but now I'm getting new set of error, I have already attached ScreenShot. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3):

```
file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
```

This error means that

> Your static library does not have any binaries for the architecture your Test App is using (i386), and therefore you cannot link with the library.

The first image verifies this - you are building the static library only for `armv7` and `arm64`.

Are you trying to run Test App in the simulator? Try changing to run on a device, which should make the architecture link errors go away. To run on the simulator, you need to compile simulator binaries for your static library (typically `i386` and/or `x86_64`).

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that under the `User Header Search Paths` and/or `Header Search Paths` build setting of the main app, the path to the static library's project directory is included. Set the path to `recursive` to ensure it detects all headers.

Comment: User Header Search Paths and/or Header Search Paths are looks fine to me. for your reference I'm attaching screenshot.

Now I'm getting some new errors, attaching screenshot for those as well.
Please have a look.

Comment: did you get any clue @Joshua ?

Comment: @SuryakantSharma In the build settings of the static library try changing `Build Active Architecture Only` from `YES` to `NO`

Comment: @SuryakantSharma Has my suggestion above been of any use?

Comment: unfortunately not. but I have updated my question. now I'm getting error for another static library.

Comment: @SuryakantSharma Do you mean the errors listed under 'I'm getting some new compile time error as below... '? If so did my suggestion of changing `Build Active Architecture Only` from `YES` to `NO` in the static library and cleaning the project not help?

Comment: No it didn't Joshua. I tried doing the same. As I mentioned in my question after error screenshot that these file are from the static library that's included in another library and this second library included in test app.
I don't know whether I'm able to make you understand properly or not

Comment: @SuryakantSharma I understand regarding the two static libraries, one included in another, my suggestion applied to both so that is a shame it did not work

Comment: that's ok if didn't work buddy. I think somewhere I'm missing something.
I'll fix this and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I met similar issue some time ago.

Solution #1
Try to do code Analysis: XCode -> Product > Analyze
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/Analyze.html

Solution #2 
Try re-create your project from new project step-by-step by coping files from your current project. Maybe at some step you will get the same issue, so you will be able to localise the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 6.3 uses swift 1.2 and there a minor changes that need to be made in order to get it running. The preprocessor issue happened with one of my projects too.

You will firstly need to open your app delegate and update the didFinishLaunching methods signature to

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool
```

You may also need to change as to as! or as? in some places.

I can only help anymore if you post some code, especially the lines which are showing the error.

Comment: issue shown in `ViewController.h` where I have added entry point of `Static library`. it simple say lexical or preprocessor issue / file not found.
btw I'm using objective-c